# FBA login not working after creating search service application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, 2019

I have migrated from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019, and system was working fine, FBA is also working..But yesterday when I created Search Service application(no powersheell), suddenly I am seeing, FBA is not letting me logged in.. While creating search service application, I used existing app pool name, is it may be the issue... Please suggest

Also, before creating search service application, I have started the Admin Search Service via powershell.

I am guessing it is something related to token configuration service, but I am not sure

Comment: I have something to confirm with you: Did this only happen to you? What about other users? What error messages will appear when logging in?  Can you find more clues in ULS logs?

Comment: An exception occurred when trying to issue security token. The security token username and password could not be validated...and the main thing is sometimes login is successful and sometimes not as we have 2 WFE might be the reason

Comment: Ok, It was due to STS, which I resolved by modifying the web config of STS service..

Comment: It was resolved after re-provisioning the SharePoint services.